# Django causes error when I'm trying to send email. Error message: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: django, django-celery, django-email

I'm trying to send email from Django. My Django settings configurations are as follows:

```
# SMTP Settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "my_email@gmail.com" # my email address goes here.
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "my_generated_password" # generated password
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "fmk@gmail.com"
```

However when I'm trying to send email from it either using celery or directly from views it says **"[Errno 61] Connection refused"**.

**N.B:** I'm using a mac matchine for the development. Is there any security reason for send email using Mac.

**Views Code Sample:**

```
def send_mail_to_all(request):

    send_mail('Celery Test Mail Subject', 
        "Test Mail Body", 
        from_email='sender@gmail.com',
        recipient_list=['repientsemail@gmail.com'],
        fail_silently=False
        )

    # send_mail_func.delay()
    return HttpResponse('Sent')
```

**Celery Task Schedular Code:**

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def send_mail_func(self):
    users = get_user_model().objects.all()
    for user in users:
        mail_subject = "Celery Testing"
        message = f"This is the celery testing message at {datetime.now()}"
        to_email = user.email
        send_mail(mail_subject, 
        message, 
        from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        recipient_list=[to_email,],
        fail_silently=False
        )
    return 'Done'
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to your security preferences in Google.

Please try changing your Google Account settings like follows:

- Go to your Google Account settings
- Find Security -> Account permissions -> Access for less secure apps
- Enable let less secure apps sign in option.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255